# How many times will okHttpClient retry the retry before giving up?

Tags: android, okhttp

How many times will okHttpClient retry the retry before giving up when the following flag 
`public OkHttpClient.Builder retryOnConnectionFailure(boolean retryOnConnectionFailure))` is set. I am using following versions.

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'

The [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#retryOnConnectionFailure-boolean-) does not mention anything

Thanks in advance.

On down voting, please provide the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When OkHttp recycles connections to reduce connection setup latency, these connections can fail. This is the primary type of recovery OkHttp does for you. In practice this will be at most one retry. It is possible that an application that makes many concurrent requests and then is idle will have several stale connections in the pool, and in these cases multiple recycled connections will fail.

The setting for this is the connection pool size. The default limit is 5.

Please upgrade to a modern version of OkHttp. The version you're using has many bugs that have been fixed in newer versions. Using an out-of-date HTTP client is dangerous because HTTPS standards have changed in response to security problems.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I cannot update the dependencies as okhttp client is plagued by [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/854) issue. And I cannot use the band-aid solution due to the implementation issues